# How to Implemt Streaming IN WCF?

Tags: wcf, stream

I am facing the problem while using the WCF to fetching the large amount of data, so I do not want to increase the "maxReceivedMessageSize="65536". So any alternative for that or can I achieve that using streaming. If yes then how ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can stream data in WCF, but WCF has some limitations while working in Streamed mode. So you might like to consider implementing a method that returns chunks of data and calling it multiple times if you don't mind handling it yourself.

Otherwise you can enable **Streamed mode**  in configuration like

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="HttpStreaming" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"
           transferMode="Streamed"/>
</basicHttpBinding>
<!-- an example customBinding using Http and streaming-->
<customBinding>
  <binding name="Soap12">
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10" />
    <httpTransport transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"/>
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

And return a `Stream` object from your Contract method. This way the data will be transferred as you read the stream object.

```
interface IRemoteFileService
{
     Stream OpenFile(string serverPath);
}
```

if your data is in a stream like a when you transfer a file. you just open the stream and return it. otherwise you can use a `MemoryStream` and `DataContractSerializer` to [serialize almost any object tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752244.aspx).

for details check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx)  and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/24/streaming-over-http-with-wcf.aspx)

While this sounds simple there are complications and limitations for Streamed mode. If you just need a simple way to bypass the size limits for a big object transfer, Consider sending the object partially on multiple calls.

Comment: Thax for reply, My exact problem is that, I am fetching the large data from the WCF service , so I got the Maxrequest size error in .cs file in server code  and nothing is going to display on the page.

Comment: can you split data to smaller size and download each part with a separate call?